How can I override Vuetify's default theme colors without creating a custom theme?
I'd like to change the default primary color of Vuetify's theme. I tried checking the official documentation, but I didn't find what I was looking for. I thought it would have been possible to do something like this:
createVuetify({
  ...
  colors: {
    primary: 'purple' // or any hex color
  }
})

How can I do it?
Edit #1
For now I'll stick with a custom theme. I created following theme.ts file
import type { ThemeDefinition } from 'vuetify'

const lightTheme: ThemeDefinition = {
  dark: false,
  colors: {
    primary: '#2377b9'
    // luckly the colors I haven't specified
    // defaults to the ones specified by Vuetify
  }
}

export default {
  defaultTheme: 'lightTheme',
  themes: {
    lightTheme
  }
}

In my vuetify > index.ts
import theme from './theme'

export default createVuetify({
  theme
  ...
})

I also found out that this doesn't seem to work:
dark: false,
colors: {
  primary: '#2377b9', // works
  primary: 'red' // doesn't seem to work
}


The page you linked contains a hands-on example. It's admirable you "tried checking" it, but what really makes a difference is reading it. Please note trying to read it does not yield the same results as actually reading it.

@tao thank you for your useful comment. I "read again" the doc, and it doesn't show an example of overriding the default colors without using a custom theme, which is a thing I don't want to use. Thanks to your inspiring comment, I also tried the custom theme approach, but it didn't work for me.

You never mentioned you don't want to use a custom theme. However, your options are limited: you either define a custom theme or useTheme() and change some props of the existing one. It's on the same page, under "Changing theme". I'm glad you find my comments helpful.

Tried the theme part? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#custom-theme-colors

A CSS framework might not be too flexible unfortunately and you need to comply to its capabilities/ways of doing things.

You can set theme colours like this in your vuetify.js or wherever you have createVuetify().  If you import colors from vuetify/lib/util/colors then you can specify the colour by vuetify's naming. Otherwise you can use standard RGB hex format.
It's detailed pretty clearly here: Vuetify Official docs
You can also set a different theme for light and dark mode.
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";    
import colors from "vuetify/lib/util/colors";

export default createVuetify(
  {
    ...
    theme: {
      themes: {
        light: {
          dark: false,
          colors: {
            primary: colors.grey.darken4,
            secondary: colors.grey.darken1,
            footer: colors.grey.darken2,
            accept: colors.lightGreen.lighten2, 
            cancel: "#FF0000",
            disabled: colors.grey.lighten1,
            highlight: colors.grey.lighten2,
            background: colors.grey.lighten3,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ...
  }
);

